# Remove black box from ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

After some googling and looking around here, I have not found anyone else with this problem, maybe I am phrasing it wrong.  However, in my legend for ggplot 2, it displays the color associated with my bars around a black box, but not filling the box.  It looks like this:

[image: bad legend yikes]

Here is the code I have

```
post_pre_active <- data.frame("survey" = c("pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
                                           "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post",
                                           "post", "post", "post", "post"), 
                              "percentage" = c(14, 18, 16, 13, 11, 11, 17, 01, 07, 
                                               17, 18, 20, 10, 27),
                              "minutes" = c("0", "1-30", "31-60", "61-90", "91-120", 
                                            "121-150", "150+", "0", "1-30", "31-60", 
                                            "61-90", "91-120", "121-150", "150+"))
post_pre_active$minutes <- factor(post_pre_active$minutes, 
                                  levels = c("0", "1-30", "31-60", "61-90", 
                                             "91-120", "121-150", "150+"))
post_pre_active$survey <- factor(post_pre_active$survey, 
                                 levels = c("pre", "post"))

ggplot(post_pre_active, aes(x=minutes, y=percentage))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", 
           aes(fill = survey, colour = survey))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Survey",
                      breaks=c(1, 2),
                      labels=c("Pre", "Post"))+
  xlab("Minutes of Physical Activity")+
  ylab("Percentage") +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = post_pre_active$survey,
                                  fill = post_pre_active$survey))
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for the nice reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some unnecessary syntax in your call to `ggplot()` that is messing up the way the legend is drawn, because the breaks on the fill and color scales do not match. You can get rid of the color aesthetic, leaving only fill, and also get rid of the `breaks = c(1,2)` and everything should work:

```
ggplot(post_pre_active, aes(x=minutes, y=percentage, fill=survey))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Survey",
                      labels=c("Pre", "Post"))+
  xlab("Minutes of Physical Activity")+ylab("Percentage")
```

Comment: If you would not mind, please accept the answer (click the checkmark) to let others know that this solved your problem!